# Anyone know why in this video, this bone detaches the arm to my mesh?

Tags: bones

I don't know why this happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZG2S.jpg. This happens with NO other limb. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It probably is just that the upper-arm's mesh is assigned to that bone or a child bone.

Select this mesh, switch to weight paint mode, and check the different bone's weights.